# how to use abjad in the Windows command line

Tags: python, django

I am following this tutorial. http://abjad.mbrsi.org/for_beginners/abjad_hello_world_at_the_interpreter.html 
I installed abjad in a virtual environment with

> $ pip install abjad

Here is my hello_world.py file:

```
from abjad import *
note = Note("b'8")
show(note)
```

When I type in the command line:

> $(venv) C:\Gideon\Professional Education\djangoTutorialWithoutGal\hellodjango3>py
>   thon hello_world.py hello_world.py file,

I see this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello_world.py", line 1, in ?
from abjad import *
ImportError: No module named abjad.
```

Why is that? 
I checked to see that I have abjad installed in my virtual environment. Abjad is indeed in the list:

```
(venv)
C:\Gideon\ProfessionalEducation\djangoTutorialWithoutGal\hellodjango3>pi
p freeze
-registry-path==1.0
Abjad==2.16
alabaster==0.7.6
...
```

I am using Python version 2.4.5

```
(venv)C:\Gideon\Professional Education\djangoTutorialWithoutGal\hellodjango3>python
Python 2.4.5 (#1, Oct  6 2013, 18:41:07)
[GCC 4.1.1] on mingw32
```

If I type

> $abjad hello_world.py

instead of

> $python hello_world.py

then the file runs, abjad creates a pdf from my hello_world.py file and opens it on my computer. [pdf generated by abjad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJTfg.jpg) This is what should happen.

I am writing a django web app and would like to use abjad within the app. I am afraid that I will only be able to do so if I can access the abjad package from within python.

Thank you.

Comment: It works now. I had a version of python saved within Lilypond. I deleted that python instance. I also edited my path variable. One thing or the other or both did the trick.